# Python requests post a query to graphql with variables

Tags: python, web-scraping, python-requests, graphql

I'm trying to get a list of offers for an item sold on opensea.io

```
def getHighestOffer(self):
    query = """query OrdersQuery(\n  $cursor: String\n  $count: Int = 10\n  $excludeMaker: IdentityInputType\n  $isExpired: Boolean\n  $isFilled: Boolean\n  $isValid: Boolean\n  $maker: IdentityInputType\n  $makerArchetype: ArchetypeInputType\n  $makerAssetIsPayment: Boolean\n  $takerArchetype: ArchetypeInputType\n  $takerAssetCategories: [CollectionSlug!]\n  $takerAssetCollections: [CollectionSlug!]\n  $takerAssetIsOwnedBy: IdentityInputType\n  $takerAssetIsPayment: Boolean\n  $sortAscending: Boolean\n  $sortBy: OrderSortOption\n  $makerAssetBundle: BundleSlug\n  $takerAssetBundle: BundleSlug\n) {\n  ...Orders_data_2g7x2d\n}\n\nfragment AccountLink_data on AccountType {\n  address\n  chain {\n    identifier\n    id\n  }\n  user {\n    publicUsername\n    id\n  }\n  ...ProfileImage_data\n  ...wallet_accountKey\n}\n\nfragment AskPrice_data on OrderV2Type {\n  dutchAuctionFinalPrice\n  openedAt\n  priceFnEndedAt\n  makerAssetBundle {\n    assetQuantities(first: 30) {\n      edges {\n        node {\n          ...quantity_data\n          id\n        }\n      }\n    }\n    id\n  }\n  takerAssetBundle {\n    assetQuantities(first: 1) {\n      edges {\n        node {\n          ...AssetQuantity_data\n          id\n        }\n      }\n    }\n    id\n  }\n}\n\nfragment AssetCell_assetBundle on AssetBundleType {\n  assetQuantities(first: 2) {\n    edges {\n      node {\n        asset {\n          collection {\n            name\n            id\n          }\n          name\n          ...AssetMedia_asset\n          ...asset_url\n          id\n        }\n        relayId\n        id\n      }\n    }\n  }\n  name\n  slug\n}\n\nfragment AssetMedia_asset on AssetType {\n  animationUrl\n  backgroundColor\n  collection {\n    description\n    displayData {\n      cardDisplayStyle\n    }\n    imageUrl\n    hidden\n    name\n    slug\n    id\n  }\n  description\n  name\n  tokenId\n  imageUrl\n}\n\nfragment AssetQuantity_data on AssetQuantityType {\n  asset {\n    ...Price_data\n    id\n  }\n  quantity\n}\n\nfragment Orders_data_2g7x2d on Query {\n  orders(after: $cursor, excludeMaker: $excludeMaker, first: $count, isExpired: $isExpired, isFilled: $isFilled, isValid: $isValid, maker: $maker, makerArchetype: $makerArchetype, makerAssetIsPayment: $makerAssetIsPayment, takerArchetype: $takerArchetype, takerAssetCategories: $takerAssetCategories, takerAssetCollections: $takerAssetCollections, takerAssetIsOwnedBy: $takerAssetIsOwnedBy, takerAssetIsPayment: $takerAssetIsPayment, sortAscending: $sortAscending, sortBy: $sortBy, makerAssetBundle: $makerAssetBundle, takerAssetBundle: $takerAssetBundle) {\n    edges {\n      node {\n        closedAt\n        isFulfillable\n        isValid\n        oldOrder\n        openedAt\n        orderType\n        maker {\n          address\n          ...AccountLink_data\n          ...wallet_accountKey\n          id\n        }\n        makerAsset: makerAssetBundle {\n          assetQuantities(first: 1) {\n            edges {\n              node {\n                asset {\n                  assetContract {\n                    account {\n                      address\n                      chain {\n                        identifier\n                        id\n                      }\n                      id\n                    }\n                    id\n                  }\n                  id\n                }\n                id\n              }\n            }\n          }\n          id\n        }\n        makerAssetBundle {\n          assetQuantities(first: 30) {\n            edges {\n              node {\n                ...AssetQuantity_data\n                ...quantity_data\n                id\n              }\n            }\n          }\n          id\n        }\n        relayId\n        side\n        taker {\n          ...AccountLink_data\n          ...wallet_accountKey\n          id\n          address\n        }\n        takerAssetBundle {\n          assetQuantities(first: 1) {\n            edges {\n              node {\n                ...AssetQuantity_data\n                ...quantity_data\n                asset {\n                  ownedQuantity(identity: {})\n                  decimals\n                  symbol\n                  relayId\n                  assetContract {\n                    account {\n                      address\n                      id\n                    }\n                    id\n                  }\n                  id\n                }\n                quantity\n                id\n              }\n            }\n          }\n          id\n        }\n        ...AskPrice_data\n        ...orderLink_data\n        makerAssetBundleDisplay: makerAssetBundle {\n          ...AssetCell_assetBundle\n          id\n        }\n        takerAssetBundleDisplay: takerAssetBundle {\n          ...AssetCell_assetBundle\n          id\n        }\n        id\n        __typename\n      }\n      cursor\n    }\n    pageInfo {\n      endCursor\n      hasNextPage\n    }\n  }\n}\n\nfragment Price_data on AssetType {\n  decimals\n  imageUrl\n  symbol\n  usdSpotPrice\n  assetContract {\n    blockExplorerLink\n    id\n  }\n}\n\nfragment ProfileImage_data on AccountType {\n  imageUrl\n  address\n  chain {\n    identifier\n    id\n  }\n}\n\nfragment asset_url on AssetType {\n  assetContract {\n    account {\n      address\n      chain {\n        identifier\n        id\n      }\n      id\n    }\n    id\n  }\n  tokenId\n}\n\nfragment orderLink_data on OrderV2Type {\n  makerAssetBundle {\n    assetQuantities(first: 30) {\n      edges {\n        node {\n          asset {\n            externalLink\n            collection {\n              externalUrl\n              id\n            }\n            id\n          }\n          id\n        }\n      }\n    }\n    id\n  }\n}\n\nfragment quantity_data on AssetQuantityType {\n  asset {\n    decimals\n    id\n  }\n  quantity\n}\n\nfragment wallet_accountKey on AccountType {\n  address\n  chain {\n    identifier\n    id\n  }\n}\n"""
    variables = {"cursor":None,"count":10,"excludeMaker":None,"isExpired":False,"isFilled":None,"isValid":True,"maker":None,"makerArchetype":None,"makerAssetIsPayment":True,"takerArchetype":{"assetContractAddress":"0x7c40c393dc0f283f318791d746d894ddd3693572","tokenId":"7722"},"takerAssetCategories":None,"takerAssetCollections":None,"takerAssetIsOwnedBy":None,"takerAssetIsPayment":None,"sortAscending":None,"sortBy":"MAKER_ASSETS_USD_PRICE","makerAssetBundle":None,"takerAssetBundle":None}
    response = requests.post('https://api.opensea.io/graphql/', json={'query': query},data=variables)
    print(response.text)
```

(In variables the "assetContractAddress" and "tokenId" are unique to the item.

However when I run this I get:

> {"errors":[{"message":"Must provide query string."}]}

And if I don't use `data=variables` in `requests.post` I get:

> {"errors":[{"message":"[400] One of taker_asset_categories, taker_asset_collections, maker, taker, maker, include_maker_assets, include_taker_assets, maker_assets, taker_assets, maker_asset_is_owned_by, taker_asset_is_owned_by, exclude_maker, maker_asset_bundle, taker_asset_bundle needs to be defined.","locations":[{"line":118,"column":3}],"path":["orders"]}],"data":{"orders":null}}

How can I use `requests.post` with the query and variables to get the proper response?

Thanks!

Comment: 1. You should provide `data` or `json`, but not both, to `requests.post()`. 2. Read the documentation for the API you are trying to use to determine the correct data to pass to it. The error message gives you a hint about what is missing.

Comment: 1. Thanks that's nice to know. 2. The documentation at https://api.opensea.io/graphql/ is not helping at all. I've got the query and the values of its variables but I can't see how I can link them with the query.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

You need to send the variables in the json data like this :

```json
{
    "query": "your query",
    "variables": {
        "var1": "value1"
    }
}
```

checkout [this](https://graphql.org/graphql-js/passing-arguments/)

Example:

```py
import requests

query = """query OrdersQuery(\n  $cursor: String\n  $count: Int = 10\n  $excludeMaker: IdentityInputType\n  $isExpired: Boolean\n  $isFilled: Boolean\n  $isValid: Boolean\n  $maker: IdentityInputType\n  $makerArchetype: ArchetypeInputType\n  $makerAssetIsPayment: Boolean\n  $takerArchetype: ArchetypeInputType\n  $takerAssetCategories: [CollectionSlug!]\n  $takerAssetCollections: [CollectionSlug!]\n  $takerAssetIsOwnedBy: IdentityInputType\n  $takerAssetIsPayment: Boolean\n  $sortAscending: Boolean\n  $sortBy: OrderSortOption\n  $makerAssetBundle: BundleSlug\n  $takerAssetBundle: BundleSlug\n) {\n  ...Orders_data_2g7x2d\n}\n\nfragment AccountLink_data on AccountType {\n  address\n  chain {\n    identifier\n    id\n  }\n  user {\n    publicUsername\n    id\n  }\n  ...ProfileImage_data\n  ...wallet_accountKey\n}\n\nfragment AskPrice_data on OrderV2Type {\n  dutchAuctionFinalPrice\n  openedAt\n  priceFnEndedAt\n  makerAssetBundle {\n    assetQuantities(first: 30) {\n      edges {\n        node {\n          ...quantity_data\n          id\n        }\n      }\n    }\n    id\n  }\n  takerAssetBundle {\n    assetQuantities(first: 1) {\n      edges {\n        node {\n          ...AssetQuantity_data\n          id\n        }\n      }\n    }\n    id\n  }\n}\n\nfragment AssetCell_assetBundle on AssetBundleType {\n  assetQuantities(first: 2) {\n    edges {\n      node {\n        asset {\n          collection {\n            name\n            id\n          }\n          name\n          ...AssetMedia_asset\n          ...asset_url\n          id\n        }\n        relayId\n        id\n      }\n    }\n  }\n  name\n  slug\n}\n\nfragment AssetMedia_asset on AssetType {\n  animationUrl\n  backgroundColor\n  collection {\n    description\n    displayData {\n      cardDisplayStyle\n    }\n    imageUrl\n    hidden\n    name\n    slug\n    id\n  }\n  description\n  name\n  tokenId\n  imageUrl\n}\n\nfragment AssetQuantity_data on AssetQuantityType {\n  asset {\n    ...Price_data\n    id\n  }\n  quantity\n}\n\nfragment Orders_data_2g7x2d on Query {\n  orders(after: $cursor, excludeMaker: $excludeMaker, first: $count, isExpired: $isExpired, isFilled: $isFilled, isValid: $isValid, maker: $maker, makerArchetype: $makerArchetype, makerAssetIsPayment: $makerAssetIsPayment, takerArchetype: $takerArchetype, takerAssetCategories: $takerAssetCategories, takerAssetCollections: $takerAssetCollections, takerAssetIsOwnedBy: $takerAssetIsOwnedBy, takerAssetIsPayment: $takerAssetIsPayment, sortAscending: $sortAscending, sortBy: $sortBy, makerAssetBundle: $makerAssetBundle, takerAssetBundle: $takerAssetBundle) {\n    edges {\n      node {\n        closedAt\n        isFulfillable\n        isValid\n        oldOrder\n        openedAt\n        orderType\n        maker {\n          address\n          ...AccountLink_data\n          ...wallet_accountKey\n          id\n        }\n        makerAsset: makerAssetBundle {\n          assetQuantities(first: 1) {\n            edges {\n              node {\n                asset {\n                  assetContract {\n                    account {\n                      address\n                      chain {\n                        identifier\n                        id\n                      }\n                      id\n                    }\n                    id\n                  }\n                  id\n                }\n                id\n              }\n            }\n          }\n          id\n        }\n        makerAssetBundle {\n          assetQuantities(first: 30) {\n            edges {\n              node {\n                ...AssetQuantity_data\n                ...quantity_data\n                id\n              }\n            }\n          }\n          id\n        }\n        relayId\n        side\n        taker {\n          ...AccountLink_data\n          ...wallet_accountKey\n          id\n          address\n        }\n        takerAssetBundle {\n          assetQuantities(first: 1) {\n            edges {\n              node {\n                ...AssetQuantity_data\n                ...quantity_data\n                asset {\n                  ownedQuantity(identity: {})\n                  decimals\n                  symbol\n                  relayId\n                  assetContract {\n                    account {\n                      address\n                      id\n                    }\n                    id\n                  }\n                  id\n                }\n                quantity\n                id\n              }\n            }\n          }\n          id\n        }\n        ...AskPrice_data\n        ...orderLink_data\n        makerAssetBundleDisplay: makerAssetBundle {\n          ...AssetCell_assetBundle\n          id\n        }\n        takerAssetBundleDisplay: takerAssetBundle {\n          ...AssetCell_assetBundle\n          id\n        }\n        id\n        __typename\n      }\n      cursor\n    }\n    pageInfo {\n      endCursor\n      hasNextPage\n    }\n  }\n}\n\nfragment Price_data on AssetType {\n  decimals\n  imageUrl\n  symbol\n  usdSpotPrice\n  assetContract {\n    blockExplorerLink\n    id\n  }\n}\n\nfragment ProfileImage_data on AccountType {\n  imageUrl\n  address\n  chain {\n    identifier\n    id\n  }\n}\n\nfragment asset_url on AssetType {\n  assetContract {\n    account {\n      address\n      chain {\n        identifier\n        id\n      }\n      id\n    }\n    id\n  }\n  tokenId\n}\n\nfragment orderLink_data on OrderV2Type {\n  makerAssetBundle {\n    assetQuantities(first: 30) {\n      edges {\n        node {\n          asset {\n            externalLink\n            collection {\n              externalUrl\n              id\n            }\n            id\n          }\n          id\n        }\n      }\n    }\n    id\n  }\n}\n\nfragment quantity_data on AssetQuantityType {\n  asset {\n    decimals\n    id\n  }\n  quantity\n}\n\nfragment wallet_accountKey on AccountType {\n  address\n  chain {\n    identifier\n    id\n  }\n}\n"""
variables = {"cursor": None, "count": 10, "excludeMaker": None, "isExpired": False, "isFilled": None, "isValid": True, "maker": None, "makerArchetype": None, "makerAssetIsPayment": True, "takerArchetype": {"assetContractAddress": "0x7c40c393dc0f283f318791d746d894ddd3693572",
                                                                                                                                                                                                              "tokenId": "7722"}, "takerAssetCategories": None, "takerAssetCollections": None, "takerAssetIsOwnedBy": None, "takerAssetIsPayment": None, "sortAscending": None, "sortBy": "MAKER_ASSETS_USD_PRICE", "makerAssetBundle": None, "takerAssetBundle": None}
response = requests.post('https://api.opensea.io/graphql/',
    json={"query": query, "variables": variables}
)
print(response.text)
```

Comment: seems not to be working. Looks like Cloudflare has been set in as a protection layer.